# Allow anonymous authentication for a single aspx page?

Tags: .net, iis

I have an Asp.Net application that is using a Window authentication    enabled & anonymous authentication is disabled. but i need to allow    anonymous access to a particular folder in which having a single aspx    page, within the application.
       Note: Entire application that is using a Window authentication    enabled & anonymous authentication is disabled.
    I tried by changing the anonymousAuthentication section's      overrideModeDefault from "Deny" to "Allow" in    C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config:
       
       Second, after setting overrideModeDefault="Allow" then you can put    the following in your web.config:
              
     
       
             
       even tried by adding a location tag in web config file

Comment: try to add code in web.config file:<location path="pagename">
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <authentication>
                    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
                    <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
                </authentication>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>

Answer (score 1):

You should not change overrideModeDefault.  There is a better way to "unlock" that section if you want to.

The easiest way in my opinion is to make this change (which does not include unlocking that section) is inside the ApplicationHost.config.  For this, you'd add something like this to the bottom of the ApplicationHost.config just above the closing /configuration tag

```
<location path="MyAwesomeSite/MyAwesomeAnonFolder">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

If you really want to place the config in a web.config, you would add something like the following to unlock anonymousAuth for that one site into the ApplicationHost.config

```
<location path="MyAwesomeSite" overrideMode="Allow">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Then you would create a web.config file under the anonymous folder (MyAwesomeAnonFolder) that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I tried by adding in applicationhost config file, but still I am getting Windows authentication pop up,        Note:My Entire application that is using a Window authentication enabled & anonymous authentication is disabled. I need to Anonymous authentication enable for one of my aspx page which reside in the application folder.

Comment: Does the ASPX page rely on any other content that may be protected by WindowsAuth?  Perhaps a CSS or JS file?   Content that returns 401 status codes will cause the Windows Auth prompt to occur.  I would recommend using Browser Tools (F12 Tools) and see what content is returning a 401.